# Git bash won't auto complete 'git u'

Tags: git, autocomplete, git-bash

When I typed `git u` in Git Bash in Windows 10, no matter how hard I pressed the Tab key, there wouldn't be any auto-completion, while there are some commands like `git update-index` and `git update-git-for-windows` start with letter `u`.

The auto-completion functions works well for other initials, e.g.

```
$ git a
add        am         apply      archive    askyesno
```

I tried both `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1` and `git version 2.30.1.windows.1`, same situation.

I wonder if there is some reason for this?

Comment: You light have better luck on superuser.com?

Comment: Git completion doesn't implement completions for all possible commands. When I stuck with such a command I do a trick: I type `git help u[Tab]` and finish the completion, then I remove `help`. :-) Doesn't work with options, alas, and completion also doesn't implement all options.

Comment: There is actually a generic bash question in here (suitable for stackoverflow, but under [tag:bash]), which is: how *does* bash do autocompletion for command options? The autocompletion for `gi<TAB>` is to look for executables whose name starts with `gi`, e.g., `gibber`, `gild`, `gimcrack`, `ginormous`, and `git`. But after that ... then what? The bash autocompletion scripts that come with Git are *part* of the answer, but all such autocompletion scripts are programmable, and that's where the topic would come in. (Also: what, you don't have the `gibber` and `gild` commands?! :-) )